# Where are yum groups defined?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

I am setting up a cluster and for whatever reason some nodes do not have all the groups required to set up Infiniband ('Infiniband Support' in particular.)

I know I could just find the list of installations the group would call out and install them manually but that defeats a more important purpose of learning to administer the cluster.

It completely escapes me where groups are defined and how to add new groups to `yum`. The best thought I had was to find the asymmetries in the `yum repolist` between the nodes, and install those missing to the nodes missing them. This had no effect and my `yum grouplist` remained unchanged.

According to every last piece of documentation I can find, the groups available are the groups you can install from and that's really the end of it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that `group` definitions come from repositories. The simple reason why adding all repositories did not work is simply that the repository URL was incorrect on the non-working slave.

I presume then there is no way of 'finding' the definitions on the system nor installing new definitions, that the groups only come as a result of scraping the repository.

As a bonus, the 'Infiniband Support' group comes from the

```
http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/puias/6.5/x86_64/os
```

repository.

install using

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/puias/6.5/x86_64/os
```

`yum-config-manager` itself comes from `yum-utils` installed with

```
yum install yum-utils
```

which can be discovered by

```
yum search yum-config-manager
```

Finally I detected the issue by viewing the content of all `repo` files on each slave in the

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/
```

folder. The file `springdale.princeton.edu_data_puias_6.5_x86_64_os.repo` contained

```
[springdale.princeton.edu_data_puias_6.5_x86_64_os]
name=added from: springdale.princeton.edu_data_puias_6.5_x86_64_os

baseurl=springdale.princeton.edu_data_puias_6.5_x86_64_os
enabled=1
```

noting that none of the URLs were correct.

The ultimate answer of how to find in which repository to find a group name in is still unknown unfortunately.